# Cannot iterate over collection to render it in Backbone App

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my ongoing self thought process by building [my simple blog app](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/ak4kucnp/1/) I am finding solutions to problems and encountering new ones.

Now successfully routing to a second view from a first one, and page is populated by the new views html.

Successfully save to the db new posts from second view, which is a form to add new posts.

But on the first view I cannot view the saved posts, in fact titles of them listed.

Js console error message is

`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.template2(each)')
    (anonymous function) (app.js, line 34)
    forEach ([native code], line 0)
    forEach (underscore-min.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    renderPostsListItem (app.js, line 33)
    f (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    trigger (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    _onModelEvent (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    f (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    trigger (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    set (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    success (backbone-min.js, line 1)
    j (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    x (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 4)`

But I have this template compiled in the view definition. And collection fetched from the db I know by using an alert(this.colection.length) in render function and yielding 2, which is correct.

So what can be the problem here with my template2 function?

html templates used in this view are:

```
<!--Post Templates-->
    <script type="text/template" id="postsListTemplate">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
        <h2>All Posts</h2>

        <ul>aaa</ul>
        <p><a href="/posts/postform">Add New Post</a></p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="postsListItemTemplate">
        <li>{{title}}</li>
    </script>
```

the view to render those templates is:

```
    var postsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new postsCollection(),
    template1: _.template( $('#postsListTemplate').html() ),//!!!Once forgot .html().
    template2: _.template( $('#postsListItemTemplate').html() ),
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.collection.on('add', this.renderPostsListItem, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template1() );
        return this;
    },

    renderPostsListItem: function(){
        console.log("view method renderPostsListItem have been reached.");
        this.ul = 'ul';
        alert(this.collection.length);

        this.collection.forEach(function(each){
            $(this.ul).append( this.template2(each) );//!this.el or this.$el. (each) or (each.toJSON()). SOLVED: use this.$el alongside el: a string, without $().
        });
        return this;
    },

    events: {//!!events attr is not a function but an object.
        "click a": 'toPostFormRoute'
    },
    toPostFormRoute: function(e){
        console.log("view method toPostFormRoute have been reached.");

        e.preventDefault();
        //this.hrefOfPostForm = $( e.currentTarget ).attr("href");
        //Backbone.navigate( this.hrefOfPostForm , {trigger: true});
        Backbone.history.navigate( '/posts/postform' , {trigger: true});
        console.log("view method toPostFormRoute have been reached.");


    }
});
```

model and collection used in this view are:

```
    var postModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var postsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: postModel,
    url: "/posts"
});
```

Comment: Probably, `this` in `this.template` refers to other object (window).

Comment: It seems you are right. I have changed the function as `this.collection.forEach(function(each){
   $(this.ul).append( this.template2(each) );
  }, this);`. the error has gone and another has come. js console now says `Reference Error: can't find variable title`, which is the template variable in the template2.

Comment: Now all done. thanks for referring to the point of context in forEach. Now I have modified inline `this.template2(each.toJSON())`, forgot the toJSON(). One of us should sum this two solution steps up in an answer to finalise the issue.

Comment: What can be the reason when I back button from the postformview to go back postslistview, that is the first page, the collection is not rendered, which is fetched at postslistview initialise? on first load of the first view page it was fetched and rendered.

Comment: So does when a link placed in the second view routing to the url of the first view.

Comment: You are talking about browser's  "Back" button? It must work - Backbone uses `pushState`

Comment: Yes. It works. Issue was the view did not rendered.